# Configure an FQDN for ingress controller IP address on GKE

Tags: https, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fqdn

I am trying to add TLS Encryption to a Kubernetes Service/Ingress Controller on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), and in order to do so, I need a domain name. I don't want to go through Google Domains and have done this before on Azure by configuring an FQDN for the ingress controller external IP address - using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#configure-a-dns-name):

Is there a way to do this on GKE? Or do I need to create a Domain Name?

I have tried everything up until step 4 [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress):

Answer (score 0):

As it explained in the [step 4](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_4_configure_your_domain_name_records):

You must update the DNS (Domain Name Server) records of your domain name.

You must create an A (Address) type DNS record for your domain or subdomain name and have its value configured with the reserved IP address

DNS records of your domain are managed by your nameserver. Your nameserver might be where you registered your domain (in other words, your "registrar") or could be a DNS service, such as Google Cloud DNS or other third-party providers.

If your nameserver is another provider: Refer to [your DNS service's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-portal) on setting DNS A records to configure your domain name.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a domain; when I did the same thing on Azure, it created a (FQ) Domain Name based off a DNS Name I provided and the region I was in.

Comment: GCP ingress does not have a similar feature. SSL always needs a FQDN and GCP is not providing you one here